# How to write an Action function with two parameter in java

Tags: java, vb.net, java-8, action, consumer

I have below function written in VB.Net, Is there a way to convert this to Java. I tried `Consumer()` but it only accepts one parameter.

```
Dim setFunc 
As Action(Of String, Object) = Sub(name, val) 
                               Console.WriteLine
                               ("Test Function. Name: {0}, Value: {1}", name, val)
```

Comment: Have you tried `BiConsumer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
BiConsumer<String, Object> setFunc = 
      (x, y) -> System.out.println("Test Function. Name : " + x + ", Value " + y);
```